# How can I set a global anchorOrigin direction for Notistack SnackbarProvider?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, notistack

I'm now setting the anchorOrigin direction (which location the snackbar appears) on each individual `enqueSnackbar()`. How can I set it once at the provider level (I'm trying to set site-wide direction based on RTL/LTR)?

https://iamhosseindhv.com/notistack/api#mutual

There's an `anchorOrigins` mutual prop, but when I try placing it at the `SnackbarProvider` it ignores it.

```
<SnackbarProvider
          maxSnack={3}
          anchorOrigin={{
            vertical: 'bottom',
            horizontal: 'right',
          }}
        >
```

This doesn't throw an error, but is ignored.

```
   enqueueSnackbar(
        `The action was successful`,
        {
          variant: 'success',
          anchorOrigin: {
            horizontal: 'right',
            vertical: 'bottom',
          },
        },
      );
```

This works.

Comment: Seems to work for me, globally. See here: https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-sea-uzytg?file=/App.js:181-259

Comment: @Nishant Hmm. Odd. Not sure why it works for you but not for me?